# why my for loop is infinite here

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

below is the js code for wikipedia search project. I am getting infinite for loop even though it had condition to stop repeating the loop. I am stuck in this problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.enter').click(function() {
        var srcv = $('#search').val(); //variable get the input value
        //statement to check empty input
        if (srcv == "") {
            alert("enter something to search");
        }
        else {
            $.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + srcv + '&format=json&limit=20&callback=?', function(json) {

                $('.content').html("<p> <a href ='" + json[3][0] + "'target='_blank'>" + json[1][0] + "</a><br>" + json[2][0] + "</p>");

                /*for loop to display the content of the json object*/

                for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                    $('p').append("<p><a href ='" + json[3][i] + "'target='_blank'>" + json[1][i] + "</a>" + json[2][i] + "</p>");

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `var` before the instantiation of `i`. I don't think this will fix your issue, but it will prevent from attaching itself to the window object.

Comment: I do not see anything here, what cause an infinite loop. How many `.enter` do you have on your page?

Comment: The only loop in the question will definitely not run indefinitely unless `i` is a read-only variable *(I know, sounds like an oxymoron)* with a value less than 20, which is extremely unlikely. As RobertMulders said, you should declare that variable inside that callback function to avoid that possibility, and to avoid the horror of implicit globals, but I doubt it's the problem.

Comment: Need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem, no one can help from the code you've given.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't [spider wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Please_do_not_use_a_web_crawler). They offer their [full DB for download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) so people don't have to do this/use up their resources spidering them

Comment: Note that you're appending a paragraph into a paragraph.

Comment: Should not be related, but it looks like you are missing a 'return false' at the end of your click() function. For ex, if '.enter' is a <a> tag, clicking it will reload the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending to each and every one of `<p>` in page.

Since your for loop appends even more `<p>` (and you possibly have a high number of `<p>` elements in your page beforehand) you overflow your call stack.

You probably wanted to append to a specific `<p>`. Try giving an id to your selector.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see in the url you need to do the following:

loop over the terms found and select the link based on the index of the element, chose a single element `.content`to append the data not a set of elements `p`, this will increase the number of duplicated results

```
  $.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='+srcv+'&format=json&limit=20&callback=?', function(json){
        $.each(json[1],function(i,v){
              $('.content').append("<p><a href ='"+json[2][i]+"'target='_blank'>"+json[0]+"</a>"+v+"</p>");

        });
 });
```

see demo: https://jsfiddle.net/x79zzp5a/

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.enter').click(function() {
    var srcv = $('#search').val(); //variable get the input value
    //statement to check empty input
    if (srcv == "") {
        alert("enter something to search");
    }
    else {
        $.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + srcv + '&format=json&limit=20&callback=?', function(json) {

            $('.content').html("<p> <a href ='" + json[3][0] + "'target='_blank'>" + json[1][0] + "</a><br>" + json[2][0] + "</p>");

            /*for loop to display the content of the json object*/
            var i = 1;
            for (i; i < 20; i++) {
                $('p').append("<p><a href ='" + json[3][i] + "'target='_blank'>" + json[1][i] + "</a>" + json[2][i] + "</p>");

            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What exactly have you changed? It's always better to explain what you've altered in an answer and why

Comment: He should be able to compare 10 lines of his own code. I declared i as variable and not using a global.

Comment: Well I can't see what you've changed? That isn't going to fix the issue also